# verify digital signatures of .Exe file from either java code on any tools on linux

Tags: digital-signature, java-security

I am trying to validate the signature of the windows executable (.exe) file using code. My code is running on Linux.
There are 2 possibilities to verify the executable :

1. Extract the digital signature content from the executable and verify it using the public key.

Problem: How to extract the digital signature from the .exe file. Is there any library that can help me do it?

2. Verify using some tool by providing it the public key and file path.

Problem: Not sure which tool can run on Linux and verify windows executable.

Answer (score 2):

Found a solution for this. There is an available library to make this happen in java.

it's an open-source Java implementation of Microsoft Authenticode: https://github.com/ebourg/jsign